# Limit of non-negative real root of $x^n+x^{n-1}+x-1=0$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_n$ be the unique non-negative real solution of a equation $x^n+x^{n-1}+x-1=0$. Prove the sequence {$x_n$} is increasing and converges to 1.

I found out that $ 0 < x_n < 1$ but just that..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let us call the unique non-negative real solution of $f_n(x) = x^n + x^{n-1} + x - 1 = 0$ as $y_{n}$.

By the intermediate value theorem, $f_n(0) = -1$ and $f_n(1) = 2$, so $0 < y_n < 1$ is true.

Note that for $0 < x <1$ and $n < m$, we have $x^m < x^n$, and therefore $x^{m+1} + x^m + x  - 1 < x^{n+1} + x^n + x - 1$. That is, on this interval, $f_n(x) > f_m(x)$.

Therefore, note that $f_n(y_m) > f_m(y_m) > 0$, so by the intermediate value theorem, $y_n \in (0,y_m)$, so that $y_n < y_m$. Therefore, $y_n$ is an increasing sequence.

It is bounded, and therefore must have a limit. But why is this limit equal to $1$? It might as well be anything between $0$ and $1$. This would stem from an argument of this kind:

> Let $x_0 < 1$. We will prove that for some large enough $m$, $y_m > x_0$. To see this, note that we can rewrite $f_n(x_0)$ as $x_0(x_0^{n-1} + x_0^n + 1) - 1$. By sufficiently increasing $n$, and noting that $x_0^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, we see that $(x_0^{n-1} + x_0^n + 1)$ can be brought below $\frac 1{x_0}$, since the former has limit $1$, while the latter is some quantity greater than $1$. That is, for some $N$, we have $f_N(x_0) < 0$. By the intermediate value theorem, again, we conclude that $y_N > x_0$ for this $N$.

Answer (score 6):

Let us define $f_n(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+x-1$.  For all $n, f_n(0)=-1, f(1)=2$ so there is a root in $(0,1)$.  We are told there is only one positive root, so this is it.  Intuitively, as $n$ gets larger the terms $x^n, x^{n-1}$ will get smaller so $x$ has to grow to compensate.  Note that for all $n, f_n(x)$ is increasing on $(0,1)$.  We are given that $f_n(x_n)=0$.  Now evaluate $f_{n+1}(x_n)=x_n^{n+1}+x_n^n+x_n-1=x_n^{n+1}-x_n^{n-1}\lt 0$ so the root of $f_{n+1}$, which is $x_{n+1}$ is in $(x_n,1)$ and is greater than $x_n$.  By the way, the sequence is bounded above by $1$ and increasing, so is convergent, so is Cauchy.

Answer (score 3):

*Too long for a comment.*

This is an interesting problem for *approximations*.

Considering that we look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+x-1$$ we could consider [high-order iterative methods](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/newton.html).

Starting with $x_0=1$ we can build the approximation
$$x_{(n)}=\frac{n^8+528 n^7+12082 n^6+42672 n^5-16751 n^4-75768 n^3+22308 n^2+17448
   n-2520}{n^8+536 n^7+14014 n^6+72044 n^5+64309 n^4-77476 n^3-50604 n^2+14976 n+2520}$$ which, for sure, shows the limit $x_{(\infty)}=1$.

The table below reproduces some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 2 & 0.414214 &  0.414214 \\
 3 & 0.543686 &  0.543689 \\
 4 & 0.618037 &  0.618034 \\
 5 & 0.667983 &  0.667961 \\
 6 & 0.704453 &  0.704408 \\
 7 & 0.732536 &  0.732464 \\
 8 & 0.754977 &  0.754878 \\
 9 & 0.773410 &  0.773283 \\
 10 & 0.788878 &  0.788721 \\
 20 & 0.869748 &  0.869329 \\
 30 & 0.903150 &  0.902592 \\
 40 & 0.921918 &  0.921331 \\
 50 & 0.934081 &  0.933530 \\
 60 & 0.942657 &  0.942177 \\
 70 & 0.949055 &  0.948662 \\
 80 & 0.954025 &  0.953726 \\
 90 & 0.958006  &  0.957802 \\
 100 & 0.961274 &  0.961160 \\
 200 & 0.977219 &  0.977711 \\
 300 & 0.983283 &  0.984007 \\
 400 & 0.986603 &  0.987397 \\
 500 & 0.988742 &  0.989538 \\
 600 & 0.990253 &  0.991023 \\
 700 & 0.991386 &  0.992117 \\
 800 & 0.992272 &  0.992959 \\
 900 & 0.992985 &  0.993629 \\
 1000 & 0.993574 &  0.994175
\end{array}
\right)$$
For infinitely large values of $n$, the asymptotics is
$$x_{(n)}=1-\frac{8}{n}+\frac{2356}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Comment: The final approximation looks like it turns the equation into $2e^{-8}=o(1)$